# Pulling a price of a specific token contract from a specific point in time

Tags: transactions, etherscan, decentralized-exchange, price, history

Suppose I pull a transaction from etherscan (or bscscan or any other network scanner), where can I take the contract address and timestamp from that transaction and lookup the exact historical value of the token at the moment of that transaction?

Needs to allow lookup on any random contract that could be swapped on a dex, even if not supported by the big exchanges like Binance, KuCoin, etc.

Comment: FYI I am maintaining historica price datasets here https://tradingstrategy.ai/trading-view/backtesting

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same - or similar. I want look up for example price of [SINGLE/USDC Liquidity Pool in vvs.finance](https://vvs.finance/info/farm/0x0fbab8a90cac61b481530aad3a64fe17b322c25d) (CRONOS chain). The closet I found are:

[Look up current price from Liquidity Pool](https://norman-lm-fung.medium.com/interact-with-cronos-single-usdc-lp-with-web3-py-1e14c62a0d9c)

[Find trade execution price given a token address](https://norman-lm-fung.medium.com/web3-py-fetching-all-transfer-events-on-single-tokens-from-a-given-timestamp-90bd6ec08e33) (Not address of LP). Trade Price is **not** price in LP back at particular Point in Time.

But both above aren't exactly it. Anyone any idea? I'd try **not** to pull all historical history and rebuild balance from zero. That's very computationally intensive.

Thanks in Advance